# Copy first two URLs fron google search results to a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, search-engine, vba

I am trying to run a search based on column a, b and c to be searched in google and first two urls to be copied to the same sheet in column d and e.

There will ve variable rows but the columns will be fixed.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

To use the API, launch a GET request as such:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
   URL = "http://www.google.com/whatever_the_api_tells_you_to_use"
   objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
   objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
   objHTTP.send ("")
```

For the response from the API, access `objHTTP.responseText`.

If you edit your post to provide more details, I can provide more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tomasvasquez.com.br%2Fblog%2Fmicrosoft-office%2Fvba-interagindo-com-o-objeto-internet-explorer&sl=pt&tl=en&hl=en&ie=UTF-8

Regards